# Grails/Groovy: Cannot cast object to java.util.Set (twitter clone project)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to make a follow user like in twitter. I'm getting an exception when I try to save the user of the currently logged in session user.

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI - /blog-dwit/user/follow/3
Class -  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException
Message - Cannot cast object 'blog.dwit.User : 3' with class 'blog.dwit.User' to class 'java.util.Set'
```

**User domain:**

```
class User {
    String email_id;
    String password;
    Profile profile

    static hasMany = [ posts:Post, following: User ]
}
```

**Controller action**

```
 def follow(){
    def followUser = User.get(params.id)
    def user = User.get(session.user)
        user.following = followUser
        user.save()

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding instances to collections you have to use the `addTo`* method for the corresponding collection. The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html) explains this in further detail.

Your action should look like this:

```
 def follow(){
    def followUser = User.get(params.id)
    def user = User.get(session.user)

    user.addToFollowing(followUser)
    user.save()
 }
```